# what is the most simple and easiest way to backup and restore on oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle-11g, backup

Im new on oracle 11g i come from SQL Server administration and the process to 
 back up and restore its very easy and intuitive.

I was searching how to make backup and restore on oracle 11g in many cases devolpers talk about [RMAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmintro.htm#BRADV89341) but i want to know if there is a more simple and easy solution to restore all elements of my DW
I dont need to make a programmed back up at the moment
mainly i want a programtically solution to operate in a windows SO

Comment: DataPump: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_dp.htm#i436481

Comment: Rman is really not that hard once you get your head around it - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/oracle-rman-backup/

Comment: Right mouse button, backup. Oh. No, that's SQL Server. I forgot. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sporri said  Rman is really not that hard once you get your head around it 
but try with this [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/recov002.htm)

Answer (score 1):

1. Shut down the database instance.
2. Copy all files to backup location.
3. Start up the database instance.